# Pass JSON from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I want to localize my webapp. Since localization through javascript only is not recommended I thought using php would be an alternative.

So with php I read a `messages.json` file that stores all localization data.

```
$json = file_get_contents("_locales/en/messages.json");
```

In the header of my webapp I generate some javascript with php according to the user's browser language.

```
echo "var localeObj = " . $json . ";";
```

So this is just a var that holds all data from the m`essages.json` file that looks like that

```
{
    "extTitle": {
        "message": "Test1"
    },
    "extName":{
        "message": "Test2"
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to access each item from the json like

```
var title = getItem("extTitle");
```

and it returns `Test1`. Any idea how to do that?

I am not very familar with json but if I just alert the `localeObj` it gives me just [object Object].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var getItem = function(item) {
   return localObj[item].message;
};
```

You could always encapsulate your i18n strings too...

```
(function() {

   var localObj = { ... };

   window.getItem = function(item) {
       return localObj[item].message;
   };

})();
```

This way, no other variables can possibly clobber your `localObj`.

Comment: I get an missing ; before statement window.getItem(item) { }

Comment: should be localObj a string? Because it's coming as a string from the php method

Comment: @ArtWorkAD No, it shouldn't be. If it is, you'll need to parse it to JSON.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD Did you copy the code as is? JavaScript has ASI, so it shouldn't be that (unless you have an IDE complaining). Are you running this code in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You use array syntax `[]`, or dot syntax `.`, to access javascript object properties.

Example:

```
localeObj["extTitle"];
localeObj.extTitle;
```

I would recommend reading something like [this](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29) to get more familier with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize javascript variable like this.

```
var json = eval(<? echo $json ?>);   
alert(json.extTitle.message+ '  '+json.extName.message);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this last submission cause it allow me to place my markers on a Google map. very efficient.

Comment: do you have any hint how to do the same task but from coffeescript?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `messages.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/javascript');
$messages = array(
 "yes"=>"hai",
 "no"=>"iie"
);
$messages = json_encode($messages);
echo "window.messages = $messages";
?>
```

Inside `index.html`:

```
<html>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="messages.php"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(window.messages)
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

As long as you tell the browser to interpret the php file as a javascript file, you can echo anything you want.