# Passing json from php to javascript veriable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a php to form a json object from sql and using `json_encode($myarr)` which is working perfectly. 
in my `javascript` i am using a util function to get the `json` which is also working fine.

```
var get_schedule_service = webservices.get_schedule + "/" + 0;
generic_get(get_schedule_service, function(response) {
    if (response) {
        console.dir(response);
    } else {
        alert('empty schedule');
    }
});
```

the above code outputs the proper `json.`

The problem i am facing is when i try to store the output in a javascript var i get an error that the var is undefined.

i have also tried putting the entire webserice in an array something like this:

```
var get_schedule_service = webservices.get_schedule + "/" + 0;
var my_json_array = generic_get(get_schedule_service, function(response) {
    if (response) {
        return response;
    }
});
```

Comment: what does `generic_get` do?

Comment: If this is `ajax` thing, assuming so, then it will not be having value on the immediate step as this will be asynchronous.. You need to make use of `deferred` and `promise` object here.

Comment: yes, its a ajax request. get_generic is a util function im using for api calls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass JSON from php to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101196/pass-json-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: What is  `generic_get`? Please, provide the full definition (the full code).

Answer (score 0):

Since AJAX request is `async` by nature, you need to pass a `callback` like this, which can be called when the response is received:

```
var get_schedule_service = webservices.get_schedule + "/" + 0;
generic_get(get_schedule_service, function (response, myCallback) {
                if (response) {
                   myCallback(response);
                }
                });


function myCallback(response){
   console.log(response);
}
```