# how to pass .json from php to coffeescript

Tags: php, coffeescript

I have a php page that queries a mysql db and return a .json file.

I want this page to be called within a coffeescript page, but I don't understand the syntax to accomplish this.

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101196/pass-json-from-php-to-javascript) that in plain js you can do:

```
var json = eval(<? echo $json ?>);
```

but this is not a valid coffeescript syntax... is there a coffeescript alternative to eval() I can use? Or is there any alternative way I can go?

Comment: As pointed out in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010133/how-to-grab-data-from-json-in-coffeescript you can use JSON.parse(json) to grab the json string and convert it into a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo do not need eval to parse a string of JSON into an object. It should be enough to use `JSON.parse`.

```
json = JSON.parse(<?php echo $json; ?>)
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is stating this from coffeescript and as far as I got, you cannot use "var"... am I wrong?

Comment: @user299791 I am not too familiar with coffeescript, but as long as you parse the content of your JSON file it should be accessible like any other object in coffeescript afterwards.

Comment: I need to call this php page every time something changes in the UI and the UI is managed with coffeescript... that's why I have this precise question...

Comment: just do `data = JSON.parse(json)` other than the absence of "var" there isn't much difference.